# Set myRange not setting anything

Tags: vba, excel

Starting at cell `B4` on `SheetA` I'm trying to copy and paste the value from cells `B4:B50` on all other sheets.

It should look something like this:

```
 ColumnB
 Sheet2 Data
 Sheet2 Data
 Sheet2 Data
 Sheet3 Data
 Sheet3 Data
 Sheet4 Data
 Sheet4 Data
```

Typically I think everything in the following code is working bar the actual pasting, and I'm at a bit of a loss what to try next.

I'm using these functions to establish `LastRow` and `LastCol`

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' summary worksheet.
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

            ' Find the last row with data on the summary worksheet.
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            ' Specify the range to place the data.
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("B4:B50")

            ' This statement copies values
            With CopyRng
                 Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")
                 Set myRange = DestSh.Range("B4")
           End With

        'End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Google up `Range.copy`

Comment: Cant see anywhere in your code where you are actually performing the `Copy & Paste`? Also, you are attempting to use `DestSh` before you are setting it. Surprised its not throwing an error

Comment: Best practice is to directly set the values of the cell rather than keep referencing the sheet to action copy and paste. That aside, your sub has no reference to myRange as a variable so it does not know what it is... Add `Dim myRange As Range` to the top of the sub and you should be fine.

Comment: Presumably `LastRow` returns a row number?

Comment: @SJR I've updated with the functions, wasn't sure they would be needed and was trying to keep it short!

Comment: Thanks. I've suggested an answer below so let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight punt as not sure what your function returns, but try this. Btw `activeworkbook` and `thisworkbook` are not necessarily the same (the latter is that containing the code, which may not be active).

And turn things back on at the end.

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'activeworkbook or thisworkbook?
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
        Last = WorksheetFunction.Max(4, DestSh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        sh.Range("B4:B50").Copy DestSh.Range("B" & Last)
    End If
Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Removed `End With` as there wasn't a with to go with it! Does the same as before, doesn't copy anything over but also doesn't error!

Comment: Oops, thanks. Have you stepped through to see what's going on? Do you have more than one workbook open? Are you copying formulae or values?

Comment: Actually it's working! BUT it's pasting the data starting at cell 403 which has now really confused me in column `b`. It's all there, just 403 cells down! Ideally `B4` is where I'd like it to start!

Comment: I guess you have more data in other columns. I've made a change which should work and doesn't require your function.

Comment: Thank you, testing now. The rows are all blank so I'm not sure what I could be picking up!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like

```
sh.Range("B4:B50").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker").Range("B4")
```

or possibly

```
Set CopyRng = sh.Range("B4:B50")
Set DestRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker").Range("B4:B50")

CopyRng.Copy Destination:=DestRng
```

[Documentation on the copy function can be found at Microsoft's webpages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy).

If you just want the values from the original range, you can set the destination range equal to them like this

```
Set CopyRng = sh.Range("B4:B50")
Set DestRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker").Range("B4:B50")

DestRng.Value = CopyRng.Value
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Consolidated Tracker")


    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Name <> ws.Name Then
            With sh
                .Range("B4:B50").Copy ws.Range("A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            End With
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! Amazing, that essentially works and is so short! I'm very impressed I've been trying to put this together for days. I feel I'm now being dense but I can't seem to move the destination from Column A to Column B. Changing the `A`s to `B`s doesn't work.

Comment: You need to change both A's to B's